# c# use properties file or xml for languages

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

In C#.NET, what way is preferable to store language syntax, in xml files or properties files?
The version I'm force to use is .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marthin, are you referring to localization? If so, look up resource strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx